# Cryptocode: remove annoying margins around figures

Tags: spacing, cryptocode

I would like to chain some boxes using the `cryptocode` package. But I can't find how to do it efficiently. I tried to change the style, look at the code... but I can't find the origin of this spacing. For now I have a dirty solution based on negative spacing, but the problem is that for no apparent reason the spacing can change sometimes and it tends to break my drawing. Any better solution?

Thanks!

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\input{include}

\begin{document}
What I have:
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering%
  \begin{bbrenv}{ctpi2}%
    \begin{bbrbox}[name=$\pi_A$,minheight=15mm]%
      \pseudocode{%
        a \gets 3%
      }%
    \end{bbrbox}%
    \bbrmsgspace{4mm}%
    \bbrmsgfrom{top={$a$}}%
    \bbrqryspace{4mm}%
    \bbrqryto{top={$2a$}}%
  \end{bbrenv}%
  % \hspace*{-2.9mm}%
  \begin{bbrenv}{ctpi2}%
    \begin{bbrbox}[name=$\pi_B$,minheight=15mm]%
    \end{bbrbox}%
    \bbrqryspace{1mm}%
    \bbrqryto{top=,edgestyle={<->}}%
    \bbrqryspace{4mm}%
    \bbrqryto{top={\raisebox{2.5mm}{\vdots}},edgestyle={<->}}%
  \end{bbrenv}%
  % \hspace*{-2.8mm}%
  \begin{bbrenv}{ctpi2}%
    \begin{bbrbox}[name=$\pi_C$,minheight=15mm]%
    \end{bbrbox}%
    \bbrqryspace{5mm}%
    \bbrqryto{top={$3a$}}%
  \end{bbrenv}%
  \caption{My figure}
\end{figure}

What I would like (without dirty space)
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering%
  \begin{bbrenv}{ctpi2}%
    \begin{bbrbox}[name=$\pi_A$,minheight=15mm]%
      \pseudocode{%
        a \gets 3%
      }%
    \end{bbrbox}%
    \bbrmsgspace{4mm}%
    \bbrmsgfrom{top={$a$}}%
    \bbrqryspace{4mm}%
    \bbrqryto{top={$2a$}}%
  \end{bbrenv}%
  \hspace*{-2.9mm}%
  \begin{bbrenv}{ctpi2}%
    \begin{bbrbox}[name=$\pi_B$,minheight=15mm]%
    \end{bbrbox}%
    \bbrqryspace{1mm}%
    \bbrqryto{top=,edgestyle={<->}}%
    \bbrqryspace{4mm}%
    \bbrqryto{top={\raisebox{2.5mm}{\vdots}},edgestyle={<->}}%
  \end{bbrenv}%
  \hspace*{-2.8mm}%
  \begin{bbrenv}{ctpi2}%
    \begin{bbrbox}[name=$\pi_C$,minheight=15mm]%
    \end{bbrbox}%
    \bbrqryspace{5mm}%
    \bbrqryto{top={$3a$}}%
  \end{bbrenv}%
  \caption{My figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am afraid the extra space stems from a bug in cryptocode and, as far as I can tell, there is no workaround besides the manual addition of `\hspace` as in your above example. I've opened [an issue for this bug](https://github.com/arnomi/cryptocode/issues/1) and will fix it with the next version.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Hope to see this fixed soon ;)

Comment: Its fixed on [develop](https://github.com/arnomi/cryptocode/tree/develop) and will be part the next release. As v0.40 just hit CTAN a few days ago I'll give it a few more days to see whether there is more feedback before sending in the fix.

Comment: Thank you very much !